# Wrapping C++ code for python using SWIG. Can't use cout command

Tags: python, c++, swig, iostream, word-wrap

I'm trying to wrap for python this simple C++ code using SWIG:

```
#include "hello.h"

int helloW() 
{
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" ;
    return 0;
}
```

and here the relative header:

```
#include <iostream>
int helloW() ; // decl
```

As SWIG input file I'm using:

```
/* file : pyhello.i */

/* name of module to use*/
%module pyhello
%{
    #include "hello.h"
%}    
%include "hello.h";
```

Now, my makefile (which is running fine) is:

```
all:
    swig -c++ -python -Wall pyhello.i 
    gcc -c -fpic pyhello_wrap.cxx hello.cpp -I/usr/include/python2.7
    gcc -shared hello.o pyhello_wrap.o -o _pyhello.so
```

as I was able to put together from different sources relative to the problem online. 
Now, once I try to import in python my library as done with the command

```
>>> import pyhello
```

This is the error I get:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pyhello.py", line 17, in <module>
    _pyhello = swig_import_helper()
  File "pyhello.py", line 16, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_pyhello')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: ./_pyhello.so: undefined symbol: _ZSt4cout
```

Which makes me thing this issue is something relative to the command `std::cout` or, in general, to the standard library `<iostream>`.

Hope someone can give me some tips regarding this problem. Thanks so much in advance!!

**NOTE**: same kind of issue I get trying to use the command `printf()` instead of `std::cout` and the library `<cstdio>` instead of `<iostream>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ImportError: ./_pyhello.so: undefined symbol: `_ZSt4cout`

with `c++filt _ZSt4cout` you'll find out that it is `std::cout` ([name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)).

You should use `g++`, not `gcc`, notably in your linker command (with `-shared`).

Or you need to link explicitly with some `-lstdc++` your shared library.

Read Drepper's [*How to Write Shared Libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) (since Python is [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html)-ing then [dlsym(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html)-ing it).

You'll better declare as `extern "C" int helloW(void);` your routine (read  [C++ dlopen minihowto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/C++-dlopen/)).

Comment: This is right, but there's no need to make `helloW` `extern "C"` so long as pyhello_wrap.cxx and hello.cpp are both compiled with a C++ compiler. (Python won't call `dlsym("helloW", ...)` directly ever, the SWIG generated function that does call it is static even anyway)